# How to build a clicker that counts with click but displays only odd numbers with react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks

So I want to build a clicker as an exercise. The clicker should be build with react components using hooks.

Es every counter it starts at 0 and increases by one. The counter is special in the way that it counts every click but displays only the odd numbers.

**Concept:**
Displayed: 0 1 3 5 7 9 ...
Tracked in background: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...

The code that I have so far is a plain counter and I started to implement an if-statement. Not sure though which logic would help me to achieve the clicker.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// Counter that displays only odd numbers, but counts with each click
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function onClick() {
    if(count%2!=0) {
      setCount(count + 1)
    } else {
      setCount(count + 1)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Use two variables, one to do the actual counting and one to render. Only update the rendered one if the counting one is odd.

Comment: You should track the "count" and the value you want to display in different variables. Every click would increment the count, but then you can check the modulus 2 and only update the variable bound to the display when it is odd.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you onClick is doing the same thing:

```
 function onClick() {
    if(count%2!=0) {
      setCount(count + 1)
    } else {
      setCount(count + 1)
    }
  }
```

Maybe you need to add other state to your app that handles the odd numbers:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// Counter that displays only odd numbers, but counts with each click
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [oddCount, setOddCount] = useState(0);

  function onClick() {
    if(count%2!=0) {
      setCount(count + 1)
    } else {
      setOddCount(oddCount + 1)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {oddCount} times</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Hey, thx. I thought of the code you have but actually this works:   function onClick() {
    setCount(count + 1);

    if (count % 2 == 0) {
      setRenderedCounter(count+1);
    }
  }

Do you know why?

Comment: @Stephan-thecurious, its a similar implementation of the issue that you ve been heading. So with the same counter you are just rendering if the count is diviisible by 2. I think is tbetter that way because you just have to handle one state , and one counter. Good solution!

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code I came up with and it indeed renders/displays the odd ones. I am a bit surprised though since the if statement checks for even numbers?!?!?! Any explanation for that?

i

```
mport React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// Counter that displays only odd numbers, but counts with each click
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [renderedCounter, setRenderedCounter] = useState(0);

  function onClick() {
    setCount(count + 1);

    if (count % 2 == 0) {
      setRenderedCounter(count+1);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <p>The current odd number is {renderedCounter}</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the continuous counter will not be responsible for updating the view (rendering) on every click, I suggest you keep it in a `useRef`. It has the same reference on every render but it does not trigger a re-render when updated.

Then I would check if the value of the `counter_ref` is odd and update the state variable accordingly.

From React DOCS: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

> **useRef()**
>
> Essentially, useRef is like a “box” that can hold a mutable value in its .current property.
>
> You might be familiar with refs primarily as a way to access the DOM. If you pass a ref object to React with , React will set its .current property to the corresponding DOM node whenever that node changes.
>
> However, useRef() is useful for more than the ref attribute. It’s **handy for keeping any mutable value around similar to how you’d use instance fields in classes.**

```js
// Counter that displays only odd numbers, but counts with each click
function App() {
  const counter_ref = React.useRef(0);
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(null);

  function onClick() {
    counter_ref.current = counter_ref.current + 1;
    if (counter_ref.current %2 !== 0) {
      setCount(counter_ref.current);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      { count === null ?
        <p>You have not clicked yet...</p>
        : <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      }
      <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```